# Ubuntu 14.04 Changing keyboard layout does not work

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

New to Linux, recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to switch between Finnish and US English keyboard layouts but it doesn't seem to work.

The keyboard shortcut I add at Text Entry settings for switching the language does nothing. The top bar displays options for En/Fi layouts and I can change between them, but the keyboard layout doesn't actually change. It's just stuck on Finnish layout.

I tried changing the XKBLAYOUT setting at /etc/default/keyboard to both "en" and "fi", but it's stuck on Finnish regardless. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "the language doesn't change"? The option you are describing is not meant to change the language of your system. It is there to match the [layout of your keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout).

Comment: Yes apologies, that's what I meant. The keyboard layout does not change.

Comment: How did you verify that switching the layout doesn't work?

Comment: I have some issue and I verified it by changing to russian keyboard and it was still writing latin characters.